# Determining location of checkbox that activated a script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I have hundreds of checkboxes in multiple sheets on a single Google Sheets project.

When a user clicks a checkbox, I want a script to activate.

In that script, I need to know what cell the checkbox that was clicked is in. Is there a way to do this without making a hundred different scripts for each checkbox and hard-coding the location of each of those cells?

For example if I clicked on this checkbox

[image]

I would want my script to know that it was activated from Sheet12:B2. If the specific sheet is not possible, then just the cell location (B2 in this case) is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use on edit / on change triggers and the corresponding event object.

Example

```
function onEdit(e){
  var a1Notation = e.range.getA1Notation();
  e.source.toast(a1Notation + ' was clicked');
}
```

Related

- [How to trigger a script in Google sheets when a value changes](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/129744/88163)

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: Some of events may be "undocumented" and/or not available in certain cases (for example, the 'oldValue' isn't available in a copy/paste scenario). 
 `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` is a handy way to see what event information is available. Chaining can get you a long way too, such as how @Rubén chained `e.range` to create `var a1Notation = e.range.getA1Notation();`.